# Is it ok to create React custom hooks that don't actually call other hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that React custom hooks are just regular functions but prefixed with 'use' to indicate to React that they are custom hooks. This lets them use the built-in React hooks (or other custom hooks).

I created a function prefixed with 'use' originally intended to be a custom hook, but I realized that it doesn't actually need to call any other React hooks. Should I rename my function so that it is no longer considered a hook? Are there any other implications to consider (like performance?). Are there standard conventions for this topic?

Comment: It's just convention. Nothing stop you from using any name you like for a react hook. The reason for the `use` prefix is that it's easier to identify which one will contain state and effect, so that the linter can check that it obey to usual rules.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67596157

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react custom hooks vs normal functions, what is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133412/react-custom-hooks-vs-normal-functions-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your hook is not dependent on any other hooks then it should be converted to normal function instead.
Custom Hooks offer the flexibility of sharing logic that wasn’t possible in React components before.

> 1. Hooks can be called from the React code only not from the Regular
>    JS functions. Hence, Hooks' scope is limited to the React code world
>    and has more power to do a lot with React code. Rather than JS,
>    regular functions could be used across application but as react code
>    guidelines keep the code more aligned to react syntax.
> 2. In the class-based components, the Hooks won't work but regular
>    functions will.
> 3. In the regular JS functions, you can't access `useState`,
>    `useEffect`, `useReducer` etc. but in react custom hooks I can.

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60133908/1723410